# Populating Text Boxes in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a small requirement and that is as follows:

I am calling a stored procedure and based on the results from the stored procedure, i want to display the data into textboxes. I am using DataSet and DataAdapter for the same. Can anyone help me. My code is as follows:

```
Dim sqlStripCmd As New SqlCommand("prcAdt_mwo_strip_det_sel", connection.conn)  
  sqlStripCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure  
  sqlStripCmd.Parameters.Add("@strip_no", SqlDbType.Char, 3).Value = txtMwoStpNo.Text  
  sqlStripCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  
  Dim getDetailsDS As New DataSet  
  Dim getDetailsDA As New SqlDataAdapter  
  getDetailsDA = New SqlDataAdapter  
  getDetailsDA.SelectCommand = sqlStripCmd  
  getDetailsDA.Fill(getDetailsDS, "getDetails")
```

I am getting the data and am able to display it into a datagrid, but how do i put it into textboxes.

Please help on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kind of depends on how much data you have in the dataset since they can hold multiple tables. One way is to find the table within the dataset that has fields you want to display and programmatically fill the textbox.

**Example:**

```
txtBox.Text = getDetailsDS.Tables("TableName").Row(0).Item("ColumnName").ToString()
```

Comment: @StartClass0830: There you go. ^^

Comment: My bad (and thanks for the edit). I program with both and sometimes I end up with "VB#"  :)

Comment: @Matt Spinelli: You're welcome. And I like your version of VB#...I'd so love to get square brackets for arrays in VB.NET. :(

Comment: I just removed the square braces and gave round braces and it worked fine. Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

yourTextBox.Text = getDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) // corrected Fields to Item

Comment: Dear, when i try this method, txtCircuitSlNo.Text = getDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0). i am not getting "Fields(0)" in the intellisense. Can you please help me on the same.